# tree structure in ruby with parent child in array format without gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a array which have list of item like this

```
arr = [
  {:id=>1,  :title=>"A",      :parent_id=>nil}, 
  {:id=>2,  :title=>"B",      :parent_id=>nil},
  {:id=>3,  :title=>"A1",     :parent_id=>1}, 
  {:id=>4,  :title=>"A2",     :parent_id=>1},
  {:id=>5,  :title=>"A11",    :parent_id=>3}, 
  {:id=>6,  :title=>"12",     :parent_id=>3},
  {:id=>7,  :title=>"A2=121", :parent_id=>6}, 
  {:id=>8,  :title=>"A21",    :parent_id=>4},
  {:id=>9,  :title=>"B11",    :parent_id=>2}, 
  {:id=>10, :title=>"B12",    :parent_id=>2},
```

...
]

If parent_id is nil then its should be the parent node, if parent_id is not nil then it should comes under the particular parent.

Based on id and parent_id, I want to provide a response like this:

```
-A
  -A1
    -A11
    -A12
      -A123
  -A2
    -A21
-B
  -B1
    -B11
    -B12
```

How could I generate a responds mentioned above?

Answer (score 11):

This is easier than you think, you just need to realize a couple simple things:

1. `nil` is a perfectly valid Hash key.
2. You can use `nil` as a virtual root for your tree so that all the `:parent_id`s point at things in your tree.
3. You can iterate through the array and track entries in two ways at once: by `:id` and by `:parent_id`.

First a tree represented by a Hash:

```
tree = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { :title => nil, :children => [ ] } }
```

We're going to be going from the root to the leaves so we're only interested in the children side of the parent/child relationship, hence the `:children` array in the default values.

Then a simple iteration that fills in the `:title`s and `:children` as it goes:

```
arr.each do |n|
  id, parent_id = n.values_at(:id, :parent_id)
  tree[id][:title] = n[:title]
  tree[parent_id][:children].push(tree[id])
end
```

Note that the nodes (including the parent nodes) are automatically created by `tree`'s `default_proc` the first time they're seen so the node order in `arr` is irrelevant.

That leaves us with the tree in `tree` where the keys are `:id`s (including the virtual root at the `nil` key) and the values are subtrees from that point.

Then if you look at `tree[nil][:children]` to peel off the virtual root, you'll see this:

```
[
  { :title => "A", :children => [
    { :title => "A1", :children => [
      { :title => "A11", :children => [] },
      { :title => "12", :children => [
        { :title => "A2=121", :children => [] }  
      ] }
    ] },
    { :title => "A2", :children => [
      { :title => "A21", :children => [] }   
    ] }
  ] },
  { :title => "B", :children => [
    { :title => "B11", :children => [] },
    { :title => "B12", :children => [] }
  ] }
]
```

and that has exactly the structure you're looking for and you should be able to take it from there. That doesn't match your sample response but that's because your sample `arr` doesn't either.

You could also say:

```
tree = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { :title => nil, :children => [ ] } }) do |n, tree|
  #...
end
```

if you preferred that rather noisy first line to a separate `tree` declaration.

Comment: I prefer your answer too mine below as it involves less iterations.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this will work:

```
parents = arr.select{|hash| hash[:parent_id] == nil }
parents.each {|hash| print_children hash, arr, "-"}

def print_children(hash, arr, spaces)
  puts spaces + hash[:title]
  spaces = ' ' + spaces
  children = arr.select{|all_hash| all_hash[:parent_id] == hash[:id] }
  children.each { |child_hash| print_children child_hash, arr, spaces }
end
```